# SQLite connection failure

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I actually need to connect to a sqlite database but i encounter an issue.

When i try to pick my `url` using `dbCredential.toURL`
I have :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
[...]
at project.database.DataBaseConnection.connect(DataBaseConnection.java:93)
```

But if I don't use the toURL method, (and i build the exact same string) my connection goes well.
Am i missing something important ?

Here is my code

```
public class DataBaseConnection {
    private Template app; // passed as argument in Ctor
    private DataBaseCredential dbCredential; //initialize in Ctor using config file



    private void connect() { // called at the end of the ctor
        try {
            switch (dbCredential.getType()) {
                case "sqlite":
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbCredential.toURL()); // here is line 93

                    // connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + app.getDataFolder() + "/data.db"); // Not calling toURL, works fine

                    break;

                // other case + default
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class DataBaseCredentials {

    private Template app; // passed as argument in Ctor
    private String type = "sqlite"; // using sqlite as default, can be changed in config and loaded in Ctor

    public String toURL() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // also tried :
        // String test1 = "";
        // String test2 = new String("");


        if (type == "sqlite") {
            sb.append("jdbc:sqlite:").append(app.getDataFolder().toString()).append("/data.db");

            // also tried :
            // test1 + "jdbc:sqlite:" + app.getDataFolder() + /data.db;
            // test2 + "jdbc:sqlite:" + app.getDataFolder() + /data.db;
        }
        return (sb.toString());
        // also tried :
        // return (new String(sb.toString()));
        // return (test1);
        // return (new String(test1));
        // return (test2);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return (type);
    }

}
```

I want to be able to change the name of the .db file using one that i will prompt in config file that's why i need to use DataBaseCredentials

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

PS: I use JDBC 3.30.1

Comment: You are comparing strings with ``==``, this will check if they are the same instance. To check if two strings are equal use the ``equals()`` method. i.e. use ``if (type.equals("sqlite"))`` not ``type == "sqlite``.

Comment: That work. Thanks, i didn't knew that ``==`` checked the instance itsef.